# Is "Next time try something in a script file should be more precise." a valid sentence?

Tags: grammar, subjects

Give the sentence

> Next time try something in a script file should be more precise.

It looks like "try something in a script file" is the subject. But why can it be a subject?

I use all the grammar analysis tools I can find online to check this sentence. They all think this is valid.

## Edit

The context is that:

> Someone was trying to do something in a specific way.
>
> I tell him that this is not precise, he should try something in a script file, this action should be more precise than that specific way.

So I am confused about the comments, is this sentence valid or not grammarly?

Comment: As it stands it's invalid.  However, if "try something in a script file" is in quotes then it's valid and (relatively) meaningful.

Comment: @HotLicks - The sentence doesn't make sense, but what are the specific issues that make it *grammatically* invalid?

Comment: I am also wondering why this question is downvoted. Maybe here is not the correct place to ask an English grammar question?

Comment: If the advice is to try _something_, it should be _that is more precise_. Alternatively, as @HotLicks suggests, it could be advice to express the phrase _try something in a script file_ in a more precise manner, in which case it ought to be in quotation marks.

Comment: @KateBunting Please see the edit.

Comment: @nnnnnn - "Next ... file" is a complete sentence.  How it it a fit subject for "should be" if it's not quoted?

Comment: There's no such word as *grammarly*.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the migration, sorry about the wrong word. I mean "grammatically".

Comment: As Chris shows in his answer, you need some punctuation to make the meaning clear. In casual conversation you can leave out _that_ from _that should be more precise_, but you need a dash or a semicolon to mark a pause in the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for all of you. Although it is weird that no analysis tool thinks it is invalid. I think I should add a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially two sentences - "try this" is an order/request/command, and "it should" is a comment about the thing you're asking them to try.

So you would say something like:

> Next time try something in a script file - that should be more precise.
>
> Something in a script file should be more precise - try that next time.

To put this into a single sentence without a hyphen:

> Something in a script file should be more precise **so** try that next time.